# air app crash when load some pict

Tags: actionscript-3

i have create a app for ios and android. it will load some image dynamically from local directory and show on screen. but i realize after few hour the app will automatically crash. please help. code below is my code

```
timer = new Timer(AppSetting.SCREENSAVER_INTERVAL * 1000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, loadNewImage);
timer.start();

private function loadNewImage(e:TimerEvent):void {
    //timer.
    //timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, loadNewImage);
    //var f_Index:int = int(Math.random() * images.length);

    var f_Loader:Loader =  new Loader();

    f_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
        //trace(System.totalMemory / 1024);
        f_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, arguments.callee);
        f_Loader = null;

        if (screensaver) {
            removeChild(screensaver);
            screensaver.bitmapData.dispose();
            screensaver = null;
            //System.gc();
        }

        screensaver = Bitmap(f_Loader.content);
        addChild(screensaver);
        screensaver.width = AppSetting.STAGE.stageWidth;
        screensaver.height = AppSetting.STAGE.stageHeight;
    });

    f_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("load screensavers image error!");
    },false);

    try {
        f_Loader.load(new URLRequest(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(AppSetting.SC REENSAVER_PATH + images[f_Index]).url));
        f_Index = f_Index + 1;

        if (f_Index == images.length)
        {
            f_Index = 0;
        }
    } catch (e:Error) {
        trace("load screensavers image error!");
    }

    //timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, loadNewImage);
    //trace(System.totalMemory / 1024);
    dispatchEvent(new Event(LOADED));
}
```

i have set all var to null but it still crash.

Comment: It would be helpful if you indented your code more neatly and got rid of some of your empty lines. Use 4 spaces for each indent and one empty line in between blocks of code.

Comment: Have you considered checking how much memory your app is using? `trace( System.totalMemory / 1024 / 1024 );` If you are loading too many images and don't `null` them, they stay in memory for ever...

Comment: hi, i already set my bitmap object 'screensaver' to null. after i load image from directory and display then i have set them equal to null (screensaver = null) but it still crash. please help

Comment: You only have to `null` the images you don't use anymore. Have you analysed memory usage?

Comment: ya, i got use flashdevelop swf profiler to analysed memory. it is OK and the bitmap and bitmapdata object memory not always increase. i have set screensaver = null is it correct ? screensaver is "public var screensaver:Bitmap = null;"

Comment: Hi, is it any method to remove this "f_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void " cause i found this eventlistener cause my app crash. but i hv delete it through "f_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, arguments.callee);" but the problem continue happen.